# How to call a tkinter Class file from another class file?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have 2 separate files, each having its own class defined in it.

File 1:

```
class AndorCameraSDK:
    def __init__(self):
             self.count = 0 
    def LiveAcquisition(self,nframes,np.ndarray[np.unit16_t,ndim = 3,mode = 'c']image:
             cdef unsigned char * pBuf #This has the data
             #.......Initialisation of parameters..............#
             for i in range(nframes):
                     pBuf = <unsigned char *>calloc(sizeinBytes,sizeof(unsigned char)
                     #-----Storing the data in pBuf into a 3-D array image....#
                     pus_image = <unsigned short*> pBuf
                     for j in range(self.width):
                         pus_image = <unsigned short*> pBuf
                         for k in range(self.height):
                             image[i][j][k] = pus_image[0]
                             pus_image += 1
                         _puc_image += self.stride
  def function1(self):
             #Something else to be done with another function
```

In File 2

```
import AndorCameraSDK as andorcamera
class AndorCameraGUI:
     def __init__(self):
           #Making use of Tkinter couple of widgets has been created, which includes a button named LiveImage which calls the function LiveImageGUI.
     def LiveImageGUI (self):
           self.camera = andorcamera()
           #define a 3D array I
           self.camera.LiveAcquisition(nframes,I) #called from File 1
     def LivePlot(self)
          # A function using FigurecanvasTkAgg to display the image processed from LiveAcquisition in the display area defined in the GUI panel
```

---

What I want to achieve:

1. The for loop to store the `pBuf` into a 3D-array has to be a function called by thread inside the same.
2. This function should call `LivePlot` function from file 2 such that the stored image frame should be displayed in GUI.
3. Both these should happen such that while processing `(i+1)`st frame, display the `i`th frame so that there is not time lag.

Could anyone please help me regarding this?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of threading but I see no evidence of threading in your code. I have tidied up the code with regards to indentation and removing superflous code. Left is code which illustrates how you can call functions between classes.

```
from tkinter import *

class AndorCameraSDK():
    def __init__(self, master):
        print('SDK Init') # Show that AndorCameraSDK.__init__ runs
        self.master = master         # Save reference to master

    def LiveAcquisition(self):
        print('SDK LiveAcquisition') # Show that AndorCameraSDK.LiveAcquisition runs
        pBuf = 'Some data'       # Dummy data
        self.master.LivePlot() # Call instance of AndorCameraGUI.LivePlot

class AndorCameraGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        print('GUI Init') # Show that AndorCameraGUI.__init__ runs

    def LiveImageGUI(self):
        print('GUI LiveImageGUI') # Show that AndorCameraGUI.LiveImageGUI runs
        self.camera = AndorCameraSDK(self) # Create instance of AndorCameraSDK
        self.camera.LiveAcquisition() # Call AndorCameraSDK.LiveAcquisition

    def LivePlot(self):
        print('GUI LivePlot') # Show that AndorCameraGUI.LivePlot runs

app = AndorCameraGUI()
app.LiveImageGUI()  # Instead of pressing a button
```

Comment: 1. Yes, this looks like to somewhat to what I require. Thank you.
2. LiveAcquisition() function does acquisition of images from camera and is stored into an array, doing this for nframes creates time lag and thereby creates a bottleneck to my code.Hence I want to process (i+1) st frame and display ith frame.
3. When I tried this code in my system, I get the following error:
   AndorCameraSDK object has no attribute master.

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly? The statement `self.camera = AndorCameraSDK(self)` passes **self** as argument and `AndorCameraSDK` saves this as `self.master` in `__init__`.  Should work ok. Else please paste the whole error traceback.

Comment: I copied the exact same code to my laptop(windows; spyder) and it works just fine.While I need to run this code in my desktop with Linux.I use cython package, hence the class AndorCameraSDK is a .pyx code where its defined :
def __cinit__(self,master):
      self.master = master 
That is the only difference I have from the code you mentioned earlier.

Comment: For which I get the error :
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/ravindra/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
   
return self.func(*args)
  
File "/home/ravindra/PycharmProjects/LiveMode/GUI.py", line 278, in getCameraStringGUI    
self.camera = AndorCameraSDK(self)
  File "atcore_py.pyx", line 77, in AndorCameraDriver.andorCameraSDK3.__cinit__
    
self.master = master

AttributeError: 'AndorCameraDriver.andorCameraSDK3' object has no attribute 'master'


Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Getting complicated with several environments. I can't think of any particular problem with this setup. My only recommendation is for you to print the value of `self.master` to console after you have set it and then again before you use it to see if it's the correct value.

Comment: `AndorCameraSDK` is a cython code written in  `.pyx` file with the class `AndorCameraSDK' defined in as `cdef class `AndorCameraSDK()`.While `AndorCameraGUI` class is a pure python code written is a separate file. Is it because of that `self.master = master` defined as mentioned previously failes ?

Comment: I'm not into cython so I can't say anything about how that works. However, if you want to call an object, you need to keep a reference to that object or you won't find it. Now, a widget will remember its slaves and you can ask it for them. But I'm not sure if a widget remembers it's master by default. Having `self.master = master` in the init of a class is a standard way of remembering the master. Bottom line is: if you don't remember your master you cannot call your master.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cpython either but is there a chance that you have to initialise self.master first (as your line `cdef unsigned char * pBuf` does for `pBuf`)?